# Make static attribute immutable after declaration

Tags: java, static, immutability, final

Could I make static property final when it is defined in constructor, not on declaration?

I know how can I create my custom class that creates immutable instances. 
But is it possible to make immutable object of some standard class?
For example Object, JPanel, Calendar or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

> But is it possible to make immutable object of some standard class?

No. There's nothing in Java to support this. All you can do is limit how widely published the reference is, and make sure that any code which has access to it doesn't mutate it. You could create your own *wrapper* type which only exposes read-only operations, and expose that freely, of course.

EDIT: As noted in comments, there's some support for this within the JDK, for collections - and [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) provides more thoroughly immutable collections and builders for them. However, there's nothing general-purpose to take an object of any mutable type and give you back an immutable view of it.

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the standard JDK provides some factories that achieve that, for example the Collections.unmodifiablexxx methods.

Comment: Not me but maybe related to Jarrod's answer which seems to say that it is possible (admittedly, using circumvoluted reflection methods) whereas you say it is not.

Comment: @assylias: DynamicProxy only works with interfaces. Hard to do that with final mutable classes...

Answer (score 2):

## Static Initialization

> Could I make static property final when it is defined in constructor,
>   not on declaration?

You can only assign `static final` attributes when they are declared or in a `static { }` block. By the time the constructor gets called it is too late, the reference will already have been assigned to `null` as all `static` code is evaluated first.

As in `private static final String s = "Hello World!";`

or

```
private static final String s;
static { s = "Hello World!"; }
```

## Dynamic Proxies

> I know how can I create my custom class that creates immutable
>   instances. But is it possible to make immutable object of some
>   standard class? For example Object, JPanel, Calendar or anything else?

You can use [Dynamic Proxys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) to have all mutating methods [like anything that is `setXXX()` for example throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`](http://java.dzone.com/articles/power-proxies-java) instead of what they actually do. I consider this approach semi-hackish, but they put this in to Java for situations just like this, so it was designed just for these types of problems.

Depending on the interfaces involved and the naming conventions it might be just as much work as just manually creating wrappers yourself.

So it is definitely possible in Java, [here is an example of disabling the `.add()` method on a `List`](http://java.dzone.com/articles/power-proxies-java) which is the start of making a class immutable.

**Hitting the metal**

You can do the same thing and even more with [CGLib](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/) but there is no real easy to use documentation or examples, so I only mention it here for completeness; as well as this would be the only way to modify the behavior of `final` classes. [JMock does this to provide Mock implementations of `final` classes.](http://www.jmock.org/mocking-classes.html). This is [deep magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_magic), but if you really need to do this, it is possible.

Comment: The specific examples given in the question `JPanel, Calendar` are `Interfaces` or *non final*. As for `Object` I don't see a use-case for an immutable instance reference of `Object`, but if so maybe the CGLib would be appropriate there I know that JMock uses it on `final` classes to provide mock implemenations.

Comment: Sure, those are *examples*. It would also be worth noting that `DynamicProxy` only applies to interfaces as far as I'm aware. So you'd have to hit CGLib for the specific examples given.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of the question, if I'm reading it right:

```
class Test{

    public static final int x;
    public final int y;

    public Test(){
        y = 16;
    }    

    static{
        x = 42;
    }

}
```

Basically a `static final` field can also be initialized in a static initializer block, and a `final` field can be initialized in a constructor.